# Class of complex matrix equal to the transpose of swapping $a$ and $b$ in $a+bi$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

A hermitan matrix H is a complex matrix which is equal to the conjugate of it's transpose: $H^T = \bar H$. However, the matrices I want to know about are not hermitan, but they are close. Let M be a matrix with complex entries, such that $m_{ij} = a_{ij} + b_{ij} i$, where $m_{ij}$ denotes the entry of the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. Then, my matrices have the property that $m_ji = b_{ij} + a_{ij}i$. In other words, we swap $a$ and $b$ when we transpose our matrix. I was wondering if these types of matrices had a name, or if there was any research done on them, or if anyone had advice on how to prove things about the determinants of these matrices. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your property can be written as $M^T = i \bar{M}$. Taking the determinant of both sides should tell you something, at least.

Comment: If $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ are real numbers, the given condition simply means $M^\ast=-iM$. If you put $M=(1+i)H$, you get $H^\ast=H$. Hence $M$ is just $1+i$ times a Hermitian matrix $H$.